# r - searchTwitter since is not working

Tags: r, date, twitter

I never had this problem before, searchTwitter (twitteR) since is not working, this is my code:

```
library("twitteR")

api_key <- "xxxx"
api_secret <- "xxxxx"
access_token <- "xxxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxxx"
options(httr_oauth_cache=TRUE)
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

s <- searchTwitter("#SiYoFueraPresidente", since = "2015-11-15", n = 50)
sdf <- do.call("rbind", lapply(s, as.data.frame))

max(sdf$created)
"2015-11-17 20:15:50 UTC"

min(sdf$created)
"2015-11-17 20:15:43 UTC"
```

I also have a time zone problem, my time zone is "America/Buenos_Aires", and the search is UTC, is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the date value in the query itself; works for me:

```
s <- searchTwitter("#SiYoFueraPresidente since:2015-11-15", n = 50)
```